# SQL R Code The tutorial problem , Predict From Model wont run. Unserialize Error

Tags: sql, r, model, predict

I ve created a model In R server , the tutorial example on the microsoft site. I have read simila texts /problems and the resolution was to wrap the model in as.raw befpore unserialize ..this does not help!!.

Note I am new to this and have not seen a resolution. I refer to the script on the page 
"Quickstart: Predict from model using R in SQL Server" on the Microsoft site ie

DECLARE @glmmodel varbinary(max) = 
        (SELECT model FROM dbo.GLM_models WHERE model_name = 'default model');

```
EXEC sp_execute_external_script
    @language = N'R'
    , @script = N'
            current_model <- unserialize(as.raw(glmmodel));                                           
            new <- data.frame(NewMTCars);
            predicted.am <- predict(current_model, new, type = "response");
            str(predicted.am);
            OutputDataSet <- cbind(new, predicted.am);
            '
    , @input_data_1 = N'SELECT hp, wt FROM dbo.NewMTCars'
    , @input_data_1_name = N'NewMTCars'
    , @params = N'@glmmodel varbinary(max)'
    , @glmmodel = @glmmodel
WITH RESULT SETS ((new_hp INT, new_wt DECIMAL(10,3), predicted_am DECIMAL(10,3)));
```

I get the following error :

```
DECLARE @glmmodel varbinary(max) = 
    (SELECT model FROM dbo.GLM_models WHERE model_name = 'default model');

EXEC sp_execute_external_script
    @language = N'R'
    , @script = N'
            current_model <- unserialize(as.raw(glmmodel));                                           
            new <- data.frame(NewMTCars);
            predicted.am <- predict(current_model, new, type = "response");
            str(predicted.am);
            OutputDataSet <- cbind(new, predicted.am);
            '
    , @input_data_1 = N'SELECT hp, wt FROM dbo.NewMTCars'
    , @input_data_1_name = N'NewMTCars'
    , @params = N'@glmmodel varbinary(max)'
    , @glmmodel = @glmmodel
WITH RESULT SETS ((new_hp INT, new_wt DECIMAL(10,3), predicted_am DECIMAL(10,3)));
```

I get the following error :

"Msg 39004, Level 16, State 20, Line 44
A 'R' script error occurred during execution of 'sp_execute_external_script' with HRESULT 0x80004004.
Msg 39019, Level 16, State 2, Line 44
An external script error occurred: 
During startup - Warning message:
In setJsonDatabasePath(system.file("extdata/capabilities.json",  :
  bytecode version mismatch; using eval
Error in unserialize(as.raw(glmmodel)) : read error
Calls: source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> unserialize

Error in execution.  Check the output for more information.
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  Error in execution.  Check the output for more information.
Calls: source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> .Call
Execution halted
"
Is the error related to *unserialize* or is it related to"

During startup - Warning message:
In setJsonDatabasePath(system.file("extdata/capabilities.json",  :
  bytecode version mismatch; using eval

Comment: I run into the same issue. It could be some installation has wrong version, based on the error message of "bytecode version mismatch". But I don't know which package.

Comment: I'm not sure if this answer applies to your scenario, but it might be worth a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57618108/trying-to-implement-a-r-script-within-power-bi-to-update-a-sql-server-database/61049731#61049731