# Trying to implement a r script within power bi to update a SQL Server database

Tags: sql, r, powerbi

I'm trying to implement a r script within power bi to update a SQL Server database. I keep running into this problem... anyone know how I can resolve the error?

```
library(RODBC)
outputframe=data.frame(dataset)
DBHANDLE<-odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=____;database=___;trusted_connection=true')

TBLExist="sbs.Iterations" %in% sqlTables(DBHANDLE)$TABLE_NAME
if (!TBLExist)
sqlSave(DBHANDLE, data.frame(dataset), tablename = "sbs.Iterations",rownames=FALSE, append = FALSE)
```

> DataSource.Error: ADO.NET: R script error. During startup - Warning
>   message: In
>   setJsonDatabasePath(system.file("extdata/capabilities.json", :
>   bytecode version mismatch; using eval Error in type.convert(data[[i]],
>   as.is = as.is[i], dec = dec, numerals = numerals, : invalid input
>   '[Adhoc] [C2R]:When user clicks on ðŸ™‚(Provide feedback) from Main
>   UI, User is not able to see submit button.' in 'utf8towcs' Calls:
>   read.csv -> read.table -> type.convert Execution halted Details:
>   DataSourceKind=R DataSourcePath=R Message=R script error. During
>   startup - Warning message: In
>   setJsonDatabasePath(system.file("extdata/capabilities.json", :
>   bytecode version mismatch; using eval Error in type.convert(data[[i]],
>   as.is = as.is[i], dec = dec, numerals = numerals, : invalid input
>   '[Adhoc] [C2R]:When user clicks on ðŸ™‚(Provide feedback) from Main
>   UI, User is not able to see submit button.' in 'utf8towcs' Calls:
>   read.csv -> read.table -> type.convert Execution halted
>   ErrorCode=-2147467259
>   ExceptionType=Microsoft.PowerBI.Scripting.R.Exceptions.RScriptRuntimeException

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a version mismatch somewhere? You should post details of versions of R, OS, packages, and PowerBI.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
library(RODBC)
dbconnection <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver=ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server;Server=Server_Name; Database=DB_Name;Uid=; Pwd=; trusted_connection=yes")
initdata <- sqlQuery(dbconnection,paste("select * from MyTable;"))
odbcClose(channel)
```

Make sure your driver version matches whatever you have installed on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try casting all of the `CHAR` and/or `VARCHAR` data types in your source query to `NCHAR` and `NVARCHAR` respectively. If your source data contains any characters with ASCII character codes of 128 or above (and in particular, 192 or above), you may encounter the "bytecode version mismatch" error.
Some additional reading here: [sp_execute_external_script and Bytecode Version Mismatch](https://itsalljustelectrons.blogspot.com/2020/04/spexecuteexternalscript-Bytecode-Version-Mismatch.html)